# Discreet boot to chromium - Raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspbian-buster, kiosk

As a part of a project, I would like to setup a raspberry pi 4 - Buster, with chromium - kiosk mode. These raspberry-pies will only display the websites we want. After succeeding to accomplish this I want to finish it with a discreet login, where there isn't any or as little login activity possible going about on screen.
The reason is that I don't want to make an impression that there is actually a working desktop computer behind it and making things look "cleaner".
Additionally speeding up the booting process would also be welcome.

To summarize: My aim is to boot to chromium discreetly and in a clean fashion.
I've tried to run my start script from different places like `systemd`, `bashrc`, `openbox` and `lxsession` autostart and more. But it always first starts loading desktop and then chromium. Lastly, I tried to autologin to shell and use `xinit start_kiosk.sh` on the start script and it says `xinit: connection to Xserver lost"`.

After coming to this far I'm prepared to learn and do a lot to make this happen. Any information would really help and is appreciated. If it is possible to come up with a `secure-r` solution I would be even more grateful.

Comment: Would this help you?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56957/how-to-start-an-application-automatically-on-boot.
They explain it for the most part!

Answer (score 0):

Try [FydeOS](https://github.com/FydeOS/chromium_os-raspberry_pi). It's Chromebook OS for Raspberry Pi, and sounds like exactly what you are looking for.

I believe you can make it autologin and boot to the browser, and there are many extensions to lock down accessible websites.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. But if it is possible I would like to tweak Raspbian Buster to do the job at hand.

Answer (score 0):

Posting some feedback on my problem. After enabling auto login to the terminal (not desktop) I edited the line in my ~/.bashrc

> **sudo initx ~/kiosk/kiosk_start.sh**

to

> **sudo startx ~/kiosk/kiosk_start.sh**

AND add

**--no-sandbox**
 to

> **chromium-browser --kiosk --window-size=$WIDTH,$HEIGHT --no-sandbox --fullscreen --disable-infobars --app https://www.google.com**

in my kiosk_start.sh file.

With this it sucessfully boots almost directly to chromium. There is some bash text to be seen, but its fast and hard to read anything. Login is not really noticeable. Now whats left is that I understand the implications and decide if I am ok with this.